# I need help to organize my project I do not know how to organize it

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've just learned Javascript, I had already learned HTML, CSS and that's all I want to make a React project.

I tried 3 times and I cannot do it; I got the ideas the way of doing it but it always get an error. My schedule is almost full I do this when I have breaks I don't know what to do anymore.

I have no organization and stuff I want this to get a job so that I can prove my self that I am not a loser I just don't know what to do anymore but that's not the point - I don't know how to organize + plan my project successfully - honestly I am lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get the hang of it with time bud! You're not a loser, you're simply learning. Here's two drawings I just did to show my full-stack folder structure. This is my personal structure for apps I've built, some with well over 100 routes or pages. Let me know if it helps!

The beginning is the toughest part - get through it and you'll be very happy you persevered.

[image]

[image]

Ensure you follow the same behavior or practice with naming conventions like CamelCase or whatever naming-convention you decide to use. If there is already a predefined naming convention, build upon the existing data and follow the scheme or the other already named folders/files.